# Trouble trying to find a word in a String array

Tags: java, arrays

For the code, it wakes a user input and splits it by witespaces then takes the individual words from the user input and checks to see if the singular word is in the text file( containing parallel arrays with one being a string array and the other an int array). For every time it finds the user inputted word it needs to add one but the problem is that I don't know how to implement either match, or compare or equalsTo to check to see if the word is in the String array.

```
public class MovieReviewSentimentAnalysis {

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO: complete me

       //make own arrays to pass by value
       //movieReviewComments = the text
       String[] movieReviewComments = new String[10000];
       //movieReviewScores = numeric values, avoid lit. values 
       int[] movieReviewScores = new int[10000];

       String userComment = "";
//     String reviewFile = "";
//     reviewFile = args[0];
       String whiteComment = "";

       MovieReviewReader.readMovieReviews("movie_reviews.txt", movieReviewComments, movieReviewScores); //string, string array, and int array

       System.out.println("Please type one line of review and when you are done press either Ctr D or Ctr Z");
       userComment = userInput.nextLine();
       System.out.println(userComment);

String[] words2  = userComment.split("[\\W]");
       double itemCount = 0;
       double wordTotal = 0;
       double totalSumOfUserCommentWords = 0;
       String test = "";
//     int itemCount = words.length;
       for (int i = 0; i < words2.length; i++)
       {
           test = words2[i];
           itemCount = wordCount(test, movieReviewComments, movieReviewScores);
           wordTotal += itemCount;
           totalSumOfUserCommentWords = wordTotal / userComment.length(); 
//         System.out.println(totalSumOfUserCommentWords);

       }

//     System.out.println(reviewFile);
       System.out.println("Incomplete assignment");

       userInput.close();
   }

   public static double wordCount(String test, String[] movieReviewComments, int[] movieReviewScores)
   {
       double storeScore = 0;
       double totalSumofReviewScores = 0;
       double numOfTimesWordAppears = 0;
       for (int i=0; i < (movieReviewComments.length); i++)
       {
           if (test.equals(movieReviewComments[i])) //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////SOMETHING'S OFF
           {
               storeScore = movieReviewScores[i];
               totalSumofReviewScores += storeScore;

               numOfTimesWordAppears++;
               System.out.println("Found"); //QUQ when will you appear!?!?
           }
           else
              System.out.println("You dun goofed"); //delete after fixing problem
       }
       double wordScoreAverage = totalSumofReviewScores / numOfTimesWordAppears;

       return wordScoreAverage;
   }
```

Comment: The `String#equals` method is case sensitive. Maybe apply `.toLowerCase()`? Show us some test data please

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You can do it the following way:

`if (movieReviewComments[i].toLowerCase().contains(test.toLowerCase())`

And if you want to test an equal comparison and not containment, use following instead:

`if (test.equalsIgnoreCase(movieReviewComments[i])`

Comment: Thank you I did try the contains method and it works I only needed to be able to find if the string array contains the word like taking hey out of they.

Comment: Cool. If it worked, please don't forget to mark it answered.